# How to parse 'normal' JSON in Erlang

Tags: json, erlang

I'm writing a simple chat server in Erlang.
I want the server to receive commands from my client (An Android app written in Java). One command consists of an JSON String, which includes the command itself and additional information which is needed to execute the command, e.g.

```
{"command": "send", "message": "Hello World!"}
```

So I've looked for Erlang JSON parsers, and stumbled upon jiffy, jsx and mochijson.
The problem is that these parsers only accept 'Erlang Style JSON'(e.g.

```
<<"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}">>
```

)
, which would be fine if my client was written in Erlang, but don't understand 'normal' JSON, which is used by the JSON parser in my Android App.

Is there a way to use standard JSON with Erlang?

Comment: How does your 'normal' JSON differ from 'Erlang' JSON...?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "erlang json" is just the way Erlang represents binary strings:

Try it yourself:

```
$erl
1> list_to_binary(io:get_line("")).                          
{"command": "send", "message": "Hello World!"}
<<"{\"command\": \"send\", \"message\": \"Hello World!\"}\n">>
```